# office.js range.load('text') doesn't return all text when there are two many hyperlinks in range

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

```
function getBodyText() {
  return Word.run(async context => {
    const range = context.document.body;
    range.load('text')
    await context.sync();
    console.log(range.text);
  });
}
```

but when there are many hyperlinks in range, range.text contains only part of the text in range.

here are links to download the docx file which allow to reproduce this bug and the execution result:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13qHZg4hGWxfydq_FbKBeAZoEM5u_k1VL/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bpQh8ArBh_D1w2ZNqZ6Sc-LjTLnl6uRC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended that you get the entire text from `document.body` object. There is a limit so you may not be able to retrieve the whole text if the amount of body text goes over the limit. Instead, you could achieve the same goal by looping through the `paragraphs` collection.

```
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const body = context.document.body;
    var paragraph = body.paragraphs.getFirstOrNullObject();
    paragraph.load("text");
    await context.sync();
    while (!paragraph.isNullObject) {
      console.log(paragraph.text);
      paragraph = paragraph.getNextOrNullObject();
      paragraph.load("text");
      await context.sync();
    }
  });
```

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/hjkim-MSFT/5098fef8112f80d657446e6dd0a9c13c) to the gist you could import via ScriptLab.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation about the limit of whole text, do you have a link to this anywhere?